# How to correctly give an ajax response to populate this jQuery variable?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, symfony

I am trying to get the below jQuery script working with AJAX. It currently populates my search box (`<input type="text" id="search-names">`) correctly when I manually define `UserArray`:

```
 $(function() {
      var UserArray = [
            {"label": "Member#1 of User1", "value": "user1"},
            {"label": "Member#1 of User2", "value": "username2"},
            {"label": "Member#2 of User2", "value": "username2"},
            {"label": "Member#2 of User1", "value": "user1"},
            {"label": "Member#3 of User1", "value": "user1"}
      ];

      $("#search-names").autocomplete({

            //source: "/member/search",
            source: UserArray,
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, matched) {
                 console.log(matched)
                 window.location = window.location + '?_switch_user=' + matched.item.value
            }
      });
 })
```

However, I've not used AJAX before so I'm not sure what I'm missing to let me pull the data from another route (`/member/search`). My JSON controller is:

```
/** 
 * @Route("/member/search", name="membersearch")
 */
public function memberSearch(Request $request)
{
    $response = new Response();
    $members = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Members')->membersAndUsernames() ;

    foreach($members as $member) {
        $data[]=array($member->getFirstname(). ' '.$member->getSurname() . ' '.$member->getMemberId()->getUsername() );;
    }

    $response->setContent(json_encode($data));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $response->send();
}
```

....this seems to return the data back to me as:

```
[["Member#1 of User1", "user1"],["Member#1 of User2", "username2"]],
```

...instead of:

```
[{"label": "Member#1 of User1", "value": "user1"},{"label": "Member#1 of User2", "value": "username2"}]
```

Comment: What is the structure of `$data` variable before `json_encode`?

Comment: Hi @cakan, I'll be back at the computer in a couple of hours to confirm but `$Firstname`, `$Surname` are both just strings and `getUsername()` would be returning the entire User object I assume(?)

Comment: I don't know what $member object contains, but `getUsername()` should also be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that problem is in the following line:

```
 $data[]=array($member->getFirstname(). ' '.$member->getSurname() . ' '.$member->getMemberId()->getUsername() );;
```

Try changing it into something like this:

```
 $data[]=array('value' => $member->getMemberId()->getUsername(),
               'label' => $member->getFirstname().' '.$member->getSurname()
 );
```